# getting CPU percentage with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, cpu, monitoring

I am trying to get the CPU usage by percent.
I saw 2 option around but non of them work for my, both of them gave me a num that according to the task manager is not correct.

this is the two command that I tried:

1. `Get-WmiObject Win32_Processor | Select LoadPercentage | Format-List`
2. ```
   Get-Counter -ComputerName localhost '\Process(*)\% Processor Time' `
    | Select-Object -ExpandProperty countersamples `
    | Select-Object -Property instancename, cookedvalue `
    | Sort-Object -Property cookedvalue -Descending | Select-Object -First 20 `
    | ft InstanceName,@{L='CPU';E={($_.Cookedvalue/100).toString('P')}} -AutoSize
   ```

thanks for your help!

Comment: What did you expect as a result of both commands? Both are a snapshot of the processor time used at the moment the commands ran. Both __were__ only accurate at the moment they ran. You can't compare them with what you see on Task Manager.

Answer (score 2):

Try to take the average of it. Here is a [link](https://www.manageengine.com/products/exchange-reports/powershell/how-to-check-cpu-and-memory-utilization-using-powershell.html).

```
Get-CimInstance -ClassName win32_processor | Measure-Object -Property LoadPercentage -Average
```

Comment: didn't work for me....
I am still getting wrong value

Answer (score 0):

In order to get only the Average, you can use the option "Select-Objetct Average":

```
Get-CimInstance win32_processor | Measure-Object -Property LoadPercentage -Average | Select-Object Average
```

If you want only the value, not the propety name, use:

```
(Get-CimInstance win32_processor | Measure-Object -Property LoadPercentage -Average).Average
```

Comment: How is this different from the existing answer?